# $SU(N)$ irreps and Young-Diagrams

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups, young-tableaux

I have read (source not publicly available) that there is a one-to-one correspondence between young-diagrams with *less then* $n$ rows and the irreducible representations (irrep) of $SU(n)$. Is this correct?

I think it is not since the singlet $\mathbf{1}$ has $n$ rows and surely corresponds to a irrep.

If I a correct what is the correspondence?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. If you have an $n\times 1$ rectangle, it corresponds to the $n$-th exterior power of the tautological representation. But this representation is trivial, since the group is $SU$. The trivial rep also comes from the empty Young diagram.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown OK thanks. Are you saying that it is impossible to get a $\mathbf{1}$ rep of $SU(n)$ which is non-trivial? Is this easy to prove?

Comment: I don't know what a "1 rep" means; if it means a 1-dimensional rep then yes. This follows from the observation that $SU(n)$ has trivial abelianization. The correspondence can be described in several ways; one of them is given by applying Schur functors to the defining representation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_functor).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yep "1 rep" means a "1-dimensional rep" (I think this is quite a common notation - at least in physics). Thanks for your comment.

Comment: It's not used at all in mathematics. I did have some sense that physicists had a convention of labeling representations by their dimensions but I always found it very strange, since dimensions are in general far from uniquely identifying.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Your telling me :) !! I have spent hours trying to work out which of the representation a question is referring to. We (as in physicists) tend label different reps of the same dimension by e.g. $\bar{\mathbf{5}}$, $\mathbf{5}$ and $\mathbf{5}'$ but even this is just convention which seems to change from one author to the next.